# c++11 - regex matching

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am extracting info from a string using regex.

```
  auto version = { // comments shows the expected output
    // version         // output : (year, month, sp#, patch#)
    "2012.12",         // "2012", "12", "", ""
    "2012.12-1",       // "2012", "12", "", "1" 
    "2012.12-SP1",     // "2012", "12", "SP1", "" 
    "2012.12-SP2-1",   // "2012", "12", "SP2", "1" 
    "I-2013.12-2",     // "2013", "12", "", "2"
    "J-2014.09",       // "2014", "09", "", ""
    "J-2014.09-SP2-1", // "2014", "09", "SP2", "1"
};
```

The regex I have is the following:

```
    //                  J   -  2014       .  09      -  SP2      -  1  
std::regex regexExpr("[A-Z]?-?([0-9]{4})\\.([0-9]{2})-?(SP[1-9])?-?([1-9])?.*");
```

and this seems to work [well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b5292b0600920c). I am not very confident about this since I don't have much expertise in regex. Is the regex  right and can this be improved?

Comment: Note that you currently allow things like `-2012.12--`. If that is not your aim, group parts that, as a whole, are optional. `(?:[A-Z]-)?…`

Comment: I need 2012, 12. Basically I want to split the string into (year, month, sp#, patch#). I have updated the comments on this.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I'm not sure a regex-only question would fare well on Code Review. We can review an implementation, class or function that uses it, but there's only so much that can be said about a rudimentary tool such as regex...

Comment: @Phrancis: I don't agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `\w{2,}|\d` as your regex that match any combinations of word characters with length 2 or more (`\w{2,}`)(to avoid of matching the `j` at the beginning of some strings) or a digit with length 1 (`\d`)(for match the 1 at the end of some strings)!

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW6lV7/3)

You can use `sub_match` class template for this aim:

> The class template `sub_match` is used by the regular expression engine to denote sequences of characters matched by marked sub-expressions. A match is a [begin, end) pair within the target range matched by the regular expression, but with additional observer functions to enhance code clarity.

Comment: I would like to split into (year, month, SP#, patch#). `\w+` matches alphanumeric, since year is just numeric I think `\d+` might be better

Comment: @Anand first my approach is for finding all matches not split, and as you want `SP1` you can not use `\d+` check out the edit, first i missed `j`!!

Comment: We don't want to match `J` at the beginning. But I do want to match the `1` at the end in `J-2014.09-SP3-1`